# Build MySQL with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2019

I want to build the `MySQL` libraries with `Visual Studio 2019`. I did it many times with previous `Visual Studio` versions, but now I'm facing the issue:

[MySQL error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCrKA.png)

**I use these commands:**

`cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DLINK_STATIC_RUNTIME_LIBRARIES=1 -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST="C:\Boost" -DWITH_SSL="C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.0.2l\x64\debug" -DOPENSSL_LIBRARY="C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.0.2l\x64\debug\lib\ssleay32MTd.lib" -DCRYPTO_LIBRARY="C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.0.2l\x64\debug\lib\libeay32MTd.lib" -G "Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64"`

I use `MySQL 5.7.25` source to build it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You will have to manually update the make file to be compatible with VS2019

Comment: @Ramhound

Ok. What is the file name/extension? There are a lot of make files in the directory. Thanks.

Comment: [Looks like more of a syntax issue then I originally thought.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html)

Comment: @Ramhound

I have tried it: `-G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32`, but the same issue is present: `CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 16 2019`. So, I think the problem is with `MySQL` and `VS2019` compatibility. Thanks.